# My animation is not starting?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying a simple frame by frame animation. My animation works on button tap, but I want it should start when the activity starts or load . I have tried **onWindowFocusChanged()** method also to start animation as per told in docs. I think i am making silly mistake. Anyone has idea.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btnalarm;
AnimationDrawable AniFrame;
ImageView images;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    images=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
   images.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demo_animation);
   AniFrame = (AnimationDrawable)images.getBackground();

}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.v("in focus", "in focus");
    AniFrame.start();
}
```

demo_animation.xml file---->

```
  <animation-list
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:oneshot="false">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/a" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/b" android:duration="50" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/c" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/d" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/e" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/f" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/h" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/i" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/j" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/k" android:duration="50" />    
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 
    AniFram.start() to the end of your onCreate().

Also inflate your R.layout.main.

Example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

layout.startAnimation(AniFrame);
```

Also check your logcat for problems.

EDIT:

Check out this from the Docs Should help alot.

[Animating a drawable](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/AnimateDrawable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use anther thread.It will work fine.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//your code 
//At last of onCreate add these lines
images.post(new MyAnimation());
}

class MyAnimation implements Runnable{
@Override    
public void run(){
    AniFrame.start();
    }
    }
```

now it will work,just check it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried above thread logic still it not starting the animation.

Comment: can you please put the xml files which contains frame animation.

Comment: ok fine.Now can you tell me which image it is showing in the imageview while displaying? Is it k ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setCallback just before you start the animation as following:

```
AniFrame.setCallback(images);
```